# How do i see if a user has voted already, using reactions, and if they have; stop the vote from counting? discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to program a discord bot for one of my friend's servers. He wants the ban command to be a majority sort of vote thing, if a user tries to ban another user, the bot adds reactions to the message and when the time limit is up, the bot decides to ban the user based on if there were 5 votes for yes. Otherwise, the ban won't go through.

However, my problem is that one user can keep repeatedly reacting to the tick emoji, which adds more and more votes for yes. I'm looking for a way I can see if the user has already voted, and if they have, make their other votes not add to the score.

My code looks like this:

````
        const user = msg.mentions.users.first();
        if(!user) return msg.reply("You need to @ someone you want me to ban");
        await msg.react('✅');
        await msg.react('❌');

        const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && msg.author.id;
        const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });
        let yesvotes = 0
        collector.on('collect', collected => {
            console.log(`Collected ${collected.emoji.name}`)
            yesvotes += 1;
        });
        collector.on('end', collected => {
            msg.channel.send(`Collected ${yesvotes} votes`)
            if(yesvotes >= 5) {
                // ban the user
            }
        });```
````

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a small issue line 5 where only the message author was able to react.
I'm storing reacting users to an array and only adding them to the count if there aren't on the list. ^^

```js
const user = msg.mentions.users.first();
if(!user) return msg.reply("You need to @ someone you want me to ban");
await msg.react('✅');
await msg.react('❌');

const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '✅';
const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });
const usersStored = [];
let yesvotes = 0
collector.on('collect', (collected, user) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.emoji.name}`)
    if(!usersStored.includes(user.id)){
        yesvotes += 1;
        usersStored.push(user.id)
    }
});
collector.on('end', collected => {
    msg.channel.send(`Collected ${yesvotes} votes`)
    if(yesvotes >= 5) {
        // ban the user
    }
});
```